# asp net mvc - bootstrap datepicker does not reflect the value in the text area

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to make a page in asp.net core and In my edit.cshtml page I have

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="BirthDate" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="BirthDate" class="form-control datePickerVal" />
            <span asp-validation-for="BirthDate" class="text-danger" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

My script is:
    $('.datePickerVal').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        todayBtn: "linked",
        language: "pt-BR",
        todayHighlight: true
    });

After trying to Edit a record I am having as result this:

[Result after receiving data from SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z31GF.png)

How can I have the value of the date in the text box appearing in the datepicker?

Thanks

Comment: what is you datePicker format when you initialize it?

Comment: data-date-format="yyyy-dd-mm" add this your datepicker input

Comment: Thanks a lot Araz, it worked! But I had to change     $('.datePickerVal').datepicker({
        //format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        todayBtn: "linked",
        //language: "pt-BR",
        todayHighlight: true
    }); and I lost the format day-month-year

Comment: great sir .....